# TouchableOpacity enabled/disabled using an async promise

Tags: react-native, async-await, react-navigation, es6-promise, touchableopacity

First of all, the touchableOpacity button is in a react navigation header.  I create a stackNavigator like so:

```
import { DownloadedToday } from './src/components/Functions'
const navigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    params: {
      button: false,
    },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerTitle: '',
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.headerRight}
          disabled = {***boolean***}
        >
          <AntDesign
            name = 'download'
            size = {23}
            color = 'grey'
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
  })
```

I have an async function in another file that I use to return a boolean:

```
export const DownloadedToday = async() => {
  //get the current date
  let currentDate = new Date().toDateString()
  //get the last download date
  let lastUpdate = await RetrieveData('downloadDate')

  if(lastUpdate === currentDate){
    return true
  }else{
    return false
  }

}
```

No problem at all returning the boolean from the function.  I think the issue is that I am working with promises so I cant just assign a variable and plug it in - the async functions always return the promise.  Im new to these issues so I am having the HARDEST time trying to figure out how to use the async function and plug it in to the TouchableOpacity disabled prop.  Any help is SUPER appreciated

Comment: Where is `DownloadedToday` contained? Is it a react component, a component which is also a navigation screen or it is just plain javascript file?

Comment: @vitosorriso - it is just a plain javascript file.  Like I said above - the DownloadedToday function works fine.  It imports just fine too - but it outputs a promise - and I need the boolean.  Not sure how to get the boolean where I need it

Comment: Ok. The problem here is not that this is asynchronous code, because with async/await mechanism you can simply assign a result when the promise is solved. The real problem is that you need to update the **navigation** prop into **navigationOptions** to handle rerender into header. I have an idea to solve this, but the `DownloadedToday` function needs to be into navigation system to manipulate that prop.

Comment: @vitosorriso I've changed it.  I have also moved the function

Comment: So you want me to write an answer to solve this problem inside the navigation system?

Comment: @vitosorriso if you have a solution I'd sure appreciate it.  Spent the better part of today on this one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the critical situation here is that in the `navigationOptions` you can just rely on `navigation` prop in order to re-render the header. I first think about **React Context API** but you cannot access the context there.

1. Basically, your `DownloadedToday` function needs to be inside a *React screen which is part of the navigation system* in order to **change the navigation prop**: a beatiful idea could be **create a custom hook to fetch the value and use it in the current screen** (I can show you this also if you ask me).
2. include your custom hook in your screen and subscribe to its changes:

```js
const { lastUpdate } = useYourCustomHook()
useEffect(() => {
  //
}, [lastUpdate])
```

3. now we can play with **navigation params**: the idea is to edit a specific param that will be responsible to disable the button, let's call it `disableHeaderButton`; assuming that this **will defaults to false** (button enabled by default), the `useEffect` will become:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // if lastUpdate is true, we will trigger a navigation action which will disable the button
  if (lastUpdate) navigation.setParams({ disableHeaderButton: true })
}, [lastUpdate])
```

4. Edit your `stackNavigator` in order to set a default value for `disableHeaderButton` param!
5. Edit the `navigationOptions` into your stack like this:

```js
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      title: 'Home',
      headerTitle: '',
      headerRight: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.headerRight}
          disabled={navigation.state?.routes[navigation.state.index].params?.disableHeaderButton}
        >
          <AntDesign
            name = 'download'
            size = {23}
            color = 'grey'
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    })
```

What is **navigation.state?.routes[navigation.state.index].params?.disableHeaderButton** ?

With this expression, you tell react-navigation to look at the params of the current active screen (`routes` is the array of the routes indexed by their current `state.index`), so if the param is edited, your navigation header now knows that it's time to re-render!

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!